# how to use metapost package boxes

Tags: context-mkiv, metapost

Try to make a text box, like "framed" text in context using metapost by following the example [mpboxes](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpboxes.pdf) or [metapost examples](http://tex.loria.fr/prod-graph/zoonekynd/metapost/metapost.html)

```
\startMPpage
 %input boxes
 boxit.a(btex test etex);
 a.c = (0,0);
 drawboxed(a);

\stopMPpage
```

It showed metapost error. Is the "boxes" package obsolete?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: why is `input boxes` commented out?

Answer (score 7):

In ConTeXt MkIV, the contents of  `\startMPpage` (or `\startMPcode`) are run twice. (This is so that all the `btex .. etex` stuff can be collected and typeset, and no external files are created). Therefore, you need to separate out the `input filename` part from the `\startMPpage` environment. For example:

```
\startMPinclusions
   input boxes;
\stopMPinclusions

\starttext
\startMPpage
   boxit.a(btex test etex);
   a.c = (0,0);
   drawboxed(a);
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

Note that in MkIV, you no longer need to use `btex .. etex`. The following also works!

```
\startMPinclusions
   input boxes;
\stopMPinclusions

\starttext
\startMPpage
   boxit.a("test");
   a.c = (0,0);
   drawboxed(a);
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

Comment: I've removed my previous erroneous answer.